# How to prevent http request from displaying resources in a PHP MVC / LAMP

Tags: php, apache, model-view-controller, mod-rewrite, lamp

I am restyiling my own php mvc framework.

I have every request handled by /index.php by default, which triggers the mvc process of routing, executing the request and returing a proper view. Each request is routed according to a single 'q' GET parameter, drupal style, like

```
/index.php?q=anApplication/aController/theAction/arg1/.../moreArguments
```

This works pretty good, and makes the clean url thing easy via mod_rewrite. Ok.

I have a directory tree like this:

```
/public
    |----themeName
    |--------|
             |----page.tpl
             |----content.tpl
             |----etc.    
/private
    |----sourceDirectory
    |----moreSources
```

What i **dont want** is files stored in private and public directories to be served directly like an HTTP request: i dont want something like

> mySrv/public/themeName/page.tpl

to show a dead template, or any resource that is not an image, bypassing my core handler - index.php.

I think i could achieve something with a rewrite configuration like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]
```

but then the framework would only work on mod_rewrite-enabled sites, because this will rewrite all existing and non-existing resources.

What i am asking for is: is there another way to make EVERY request served by a resource (such an index.php) of my choice, existing or non-existing ones?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you have templates in public folders?

Comment: Because i usually share template folder with generic resources like css, js, etc.

Comment: That's not a good idea, imho.

Answer (score 4):

Just store all your templates etc outside of the public_html folder.

This will allow PHP to have access, but the outside world cannot get to the file.

Comment: +1 anyway. But why just not to use a dumb constant to prevent direct access to them?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and more portable way would be to pull everything except your `index.php` out of the document root. PHP can still include files and do everything else.

I have not tried this, but if you put an index.php *outside* the old document tree

```
---/ app / new-index.php
   |
   / public / 
   |
   / private / ...
   |
   index.php
```

and then add at the beginning of `new-index.php`

```
<?php
    chdir('..');
    require 'index.php';
?>
```

and finally reconfigure Apache so that the DocumentRoot actually becomes `/app`, then everything should work as before -- except that any URLs but '/' stop making sense for Apache, and all can be made to land on a suitable ErrorDocument 404.

**Note**: "everything should work", *except* HTTP redirections. You can read a non-interpreted PHP file from the FS, but you can no longer get its interpreted content from, say, Apache on localhost. Also, you ought to verify that any existing code does not make use of the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` global variable; if necessary you may overwrite it.